# Does hydrogen-infused water have these health benefits?

Tags: water, nutritional-supplements, antioxidant

I recently saw a local shop selling packages of water infused with hydrogen gas.  It was alleged that hydrogen is an antioxidant and therefore drinking hydrogen-infused water would have various health benefits.

One manufacturer of hydrogen water [claims](http://www.perriconehydrogenwater.com/faq/) that their product "Has beneficial effects on all organ systems including the skin;
Acts as a natural antioxidant; 
Increases energy;
Improves athletic performance."  They include references to [some studies](http://www.perriconehydrogenwater.com/articles/).

(There are other claims like "[When infused in water [hydrogen] provides multiple benefits, including increased energy and antioxidant activity](http://www.perriconehydrogenwater.com/science/)", so I interpret their claim to be that the supposed benefits are due specifically to the hydrogen, over and above the benefits of drinking plain water.  Thanks to Nat for helping clarify this.)

Is there good-quality evidence that this and similar products provide the claimed benefits to a significant degree?

Comment: If people find other examples of specific health claims for hydrogen-infused water, I'd be happy to have them added to the question.

Comment: Seems like we could separate this question into two parts: **(1)**  Does hydrogen water have claimed benefits under ideal laboratory conditions?  **(2)**  Does hydrogen water maintain any such beneficial properties as typically consumed by drinkers?

Comment: Looks like the Henry's constant for hydrogen-in-water is about [7.8*10^{-4} mol/(L*atm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law#Values_of_Henry.27s_law_constants), and the partial-pressure-of-hydrogen in Earth's atmosphere is about [5.5*10^{-7} atm}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_chemistry#Atmospheric_composition), for an equilibrium water concentration of about [4.29*10^{-10} mol/L](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7.8*10%5E%7B-4%7D+mol%2F(L*atm)+*+(5.5*10%5E%7B-7%7D+atm)).  [...]

Comment: [...]  [This source](http://www.foxnews.com/lifestyle/2017/06/05/hydrogen-water-truth-about-this-new-trend.html) reports the same figure, as "_0.0000004 millimoles per liter_", which is 4*10^{-10} mol/L.

Comment: The first study in the linked list of studies has a laughably small sample size of 8 people, 4 in the control group and 4 in the experiment group. It was also published in a low impact (second rate) scientific journal. That particular study does not appear to be very good quality.

Comment: Isn't the way that hydrogen removes oxygen from being available a somewhat explosive process? But the real beauty of this claim is that, since the by-product of hydrogen oxidizing is water, if you say "I don't think it made any difference, it's just water" then that's PROOF that it worked!

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Explosions require chain reactions, so it's probably safe enough when it works-as-intended.  But you're right, a problem could arise if the dissolved hydrogen degasses out into a concentrated pocket in a beverage container, in which case there may be explosive potential.  Same thing happens with soda cans when the CO2 degasses out of them (causing that sound when a can's opened), but CO2's flame-retardant, so the issue's avoided there.

Comment: @Nat - Not claiming that in a single bottle of water you risk fatal mishap, so much, but, clearly, pure hydrogen would be stored, handled and managed on a much larger scale at whatever production facility they use to package this particular snake oil.  More a question of the wisdom of wanting to use straight-up, pure elemental hydrogen, in general. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgWHbpMVQ1U

Comment: There is a big difference between antioxidant and _fuel_.

Comment: @T.Sar What do you mean?

Comment: Can people please use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68731/hydrogen-water) for general discussion of hydrogen water?  It's all very interesting but I would rather not be notified every time.   Comments are fine if they are a direct suggestion for improving the question.

Comment: @Nat - Not if the can is made from magnesium.

Comment: I'm reading those articles referenced by this company and it's funny that one of the most frequent chain of words in them is "no objective clinical effects were observed", despite their claims that hydrogen-infused water improves stuff.

Comment: Deeply buried in their "Terms of Use" they have this: "YOU SHOULD NOT CONSTRUE WEBSITE CONTENT AS ANY WARRANTY OR RECOMMENDATION OF THE MEDICAL, HEALTH AND/OR NUTITIONAL BENEFITS OF DR. PERRICONE HYDROGEN WATER OR OTHER FOODS, TREATMENTS, PROVIDERS OR SERVICES." I'm not sure if this standard practice or not, but this already raised some red flags to me. If fact, their "Terms of use" section is full of legalese similar to this. Like "deeply buried in their "Terms of Use" they have this.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the product in question is (very slightly) an antioxidant. It does have all of those stated health benefits. The health benefits do not spring from the water being an anti-oxidant, but your source never claimed they did. The health benefits arise from you drinking water.

Those claims are principally true, although maybe not as impressive as you might expect. The claim that Hydrogen infused water "Has beneficial effects on all organ systems including the skin; Acts as a natural antioxidant; Increases energy; Improves athletic performance.".

Hydrogen infused water is, by volume or weight, principally water.

Water has been demonstrated to reduce dehydration, [a medical term used to describe a condition caused by the excessive loss of water from the body](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dehydration).

Dehydration causes dry skin, and reduces skin elasticity. Drinking hydrogen infused water counteracts these symptoms and thus has beneficial effects on the skin.

Dehydration negatively impacts the heart and the brain, the operation of which effect all the other organs. So Hydrogen infused water has beneficial effects on all organ systems.

Dehydration causes lethargy, high pulse rate, and dizziness. By removing these symptoms, Hydrogen infused water improves athletic performance.

Dehydration is a very serious condition, which can lead to shock, coma and death. There are very significant benefits from taking Hydrogen infused water to cure or prevent dehydration.

The product in question likely is an antioxidant. [Tap water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/what-chemicals-are-in-tap-water-that-gives-it-a-slightly-basic-ph-level), and most bottled waters are slightly alkaline. Alkaline water is an antioxidant. I do not have enough information to determine if the source here is being correct in a technical sense, or in a practical sense (i.e. is it enough of an antioxidant to have a health benefit).

Comment: The communicated claim is that hydrogen-water provides some special benefit beyond what water would, so that's the claim that needs to be fact-checked.

Comment: Thanks @Nat, I had overlooked that.  Now I agree that the claim is explicitly  attributing the benefits specifically to the hydrogen.